# Move evil tag to beginning of mode line

Tags: evil, mode-line

This question is pretty self explanatory. I'd like to move `evil-mode-line-tag` to the beginning of `mode-line-format`. However, when I try my instinctive solution:

```el
(setq-default mode-line-format (cons 
                                 'evil-mode-line-tag 
                                 (delete 'evil-mode-line-tag 
                                          mode-line-format)))
```

My changes seem to be reverted instantly. Why is this, and how can I achieve the effect I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evil does modify the mode line on its own and refreshes it regularly (according to the code at activation and state changes).  The placement of its tag depends on `evil-mode-line-format`, theoretically it should be possible for the code to perform `(cons 'evil-mode-line-tag mode-line-format)`, but I've went with `(setq evil-mode-line-format '(before . mode-line-front-space))` instead as that does definitely work for me.